# Store KeyPoints and descriptors in Mat structure/list

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

I would like to store all my precalculated Keypoints/decriptors of several images in a Mat list/structure or something, so I could be able to use them later to match them with others image descriptors. 
Do you have an idea?

Apparently, there is a way to use

```
List<Mat>
```

but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the descriptor of one image in one `Mat` variable. So, basically you have one `Mat` for one descriptors. So, if you have 100 descriptors then, all of these decriptors should be present in a single `Mat`. You can do it as following:

**Step-1:** Declare a `vector` of `Mat` type.

```
vector<Mat> allDescriptors;
```

**Step-2:** Then find descriptors for each image and store it in `Mat` format

```
Mat newImageDescriptor;
```

**Step-3:** finally, push the descriptor calculated above into the vector.

```
allDescriptors.push_back(newImageDescriptor);
```

***Repeat step-2 & 3 for all of your images***

**Now, you can access them as following:**

You can access the data in `vector` as you do it in case of `arrays`

so `allDescriptors[0]` will give you the first descriptor in `Mat` format

So, by using a `for loop`, you can access all of your descriptors.

```
for(int i=0; i<allDescriptors.size(); i++)
{
    Mat accessedDescriptor;
    allDescriptors[i].copyTo(accessedDescriptor);
}
```

Comment: i am going to update my answer...just wait for a minute

Comment: i have not tested the code but the logic is correct and i have used it before so, let me know if your get any error.

Comment: hello skm, I just ran my code, it works perfectly, but how about storing allDescriptors within another vector<Mat> ? I tried copyTo but i'm facing an exception.

Comment: i have kept an another answer..have a look on it

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are stored in contiguous array you can [assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/assign) them to a list at once with:

```
#include <list>
std::list<Mat> l;
l.assign( ptr, ptr + sz); // where ptr is a pointer to array of Mat s
                          // and sz is the size of array
```

Create precalculated elements:

```
Mat mat1;
Mat mat2;
```

And the list of elements of this type:

```
#include <list>
std::list<Mat> l;
```

Add elements to list:

```
l.push_back( mat1);
l.push_back( mat2)
```

note: there are other modifiers that you can use to insert elements. You will find a description of them [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). There are other  containers which usage you can consider. Selection of appropriate container is very important. You have to take into account the operations that will be crucial to you, which will be called most often.

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding to your another question of copying the `vector<Mat>` to another `vector<Mat>`

Lets say you have one vector `vector<Mat> des1` and you want to copy it to `vector<Mat> des2` then you should do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<des1.size(); i++)
{
    des1[i].copyTo(des2[i]);
}
```

Remember that `vector<Mat>` is something like an arrya of `Mat`. So, how can you copy a vector to another vector by `CopyTo` which is used to copy a Matrix.